# Run app in background and send data to server in background when the application is in foreground or in background

Tags: ios

I have to send the data to server in background while the application is in foreground or background and at the same time when application enters background location should update continuously and send the data to server in background. But this app running in background for location updates and sending data in background conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at 
[`application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)? (iOS7 only)

Tutorial: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/

Answer (score 0):

continuously?? Its not possible to run your application in background mode so you can run your download for some specific time which you can ask from iOS depend on the iOS.